# Avoid Listing Sale Orders based on Products

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

My Requirement is not to show the Sales Orders whose Product Code in the list.
Issue is, as Sales Orders contain multiple Products, my domain filter is going wrong.
Filter Domain i wrote is,

```
[['state', '!=', 'done'], ['product_id.default_code', 'not in', ['12345', '12311','45345']]]
```

Sale Orders only with one product and whose Product Code in the list, are getting filtered.
But, Sale Orders with multiple Products and in which one product's default code is in the specified list are also listing.
How to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

You should create one related field store False in sale order line.

Ex:

```
class sale_order_line(models.Model):
    _inherit="sale.order.line"

    default_code=fields.Char("default code",related="product_id.default_code",store=False,readonly=True)
```

**Now you can give Domain based on sale order line.**

**[['state', '!=', 'done'], ['order_line.default_code', 'not in', ['12345', '12311','45345']]]**

Comment: Why not just use `order_line.product_id.default_code`?

Comment: product_id is a relational field at Sale Order . There is noting wrong in Filter. Its working fine, but not achieving my requirement.